# Spring controller redirects to wrong url

Tags: spring, apache, tomcat, redirect, dns

I have a little problem with my spring web application. I run my application on VPS with Tomcat. VPS comes with url `24524.vps.com` for example. I parked my domain, to redirect `domain.com` for example to my vps server hostname. And the problem comes here:

All my controllers and pages work with `domain.com` url. But when I use `return "redirect:main";` in my controller, I get redirected to url `24524.vps.com/main` and not to `domain.com/main`.

How to force redirecting to url `domain.com/main`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem wanst in spring.... VPS host was `24524.vps.com` so thats why spring redirected to `24524.vps.com`... I forced my VPS to use `domain.com` as host and all problems gone.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this is the problem but when i use redirect i put a slash in front of the link.
return "redirect:/main";